# changing the calender height and width of AngularJS UI Bootstrap datepicker

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using Angularjs UI Bootstrap datepicker (http://plnkr.co/edit/kMXeOm5ct4pPFH0ZJc8u?p=preview), which is working fine. But I need to change the height and width of the calender. Is it possible?. The following is my code :

```
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <p class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
              </span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with CSS:

```
.dropdown-menu table {
  height: 300px;
  width: 350px;
}
```

Here is [a fork of your plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/JK22DkNR8ZbNBi65lQWu?p=preview).

Comment: Turns out.. you can increase the width and height , but reducing it kind of takes a hard stop at some values.

Comment: Same here it doesnt seem to reduce

Comment: If you need to decrease its size, try 'zoom: 0.5' to proportionally reduce the size of all the internal elements.

Answer (score 1):

`.dropdown-menu table { height: 120px; width: 120px; }`

Comment: Although you use different units, this is functionally and syntactically identical to [the top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31737570/3025856).

Answer (score 0):

You Can change popup height and width changing `.btn` padding

```
.btn {
    padding: 1px 2px;
  }
```

But this will change your pop-up button size

Here is a fork of your [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/4srYdusBpb5FRQHyHiqp?p=preview).